# Editing a Misleading Title

Tags: discussion, editing

The question [Math topics that reward fighting against pattern recognition](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/math-topics-that-reward-fighting-against-pattern-recognition) has a very misleading title.  The question seems to be about using patterns but is really about using algorithms and cookbook methods.
I wrote the following comment:

> I don't think the problem is patterns as much as relying on
>   algorithms/cookbook methods to solve problems. I had a student who
>   would always solve simultaneous equations by substitution no matter
>   how messy the algebra, even when it was clear (to me) that adding and
>   subtracting the equations would be much easier in eliminating one
>   variable. I would like to suggest that you look for problems that are
>   exceptions to algorithms and not worry about patterns.

I was pleased when the OP responded:

> you are absolutely right, pattern-recognition is really not my issue.
>   I should have titled the question "Math topics that reward going
>   beyond cookbook methods" or something similar

I wrote:

> You can still edit it and change the title!

However the OP shows no sign of doing so and meanwhile there is continual discussion of patterns in mathematics and misunderstanding of what, in my opinion, is a question worthy of discussion.

Would it be appropriate for me to edit the title and the question to reflect what is surely the OP's intention or is there another way to better way to handle this.

Comment: I think it is fair to edit the post and change the title specifically because OP suggested an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think it would be appropriate for you to edit the title yourself.  The OP has clearly agreed to it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think that going forward, you should edit the title for clarity even if the OP does not agree to it in a comment!